# Replace linux kernel syscall : Unknown symbol current_kprobe

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to replace a linux kernel syscall (sys_read) with a loadable module and using kprobes.

So, in the handler_pre I replace the regs->ip value with a function pointer to the function i want to be called, then i call `reset_current_kprobe` :

```
static int handler_pre(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "pre_handler: p->addr = 0x%p, ip = %lx,"
            " flags = 0x%lx\n",
        p->addr, regs->ip, regs->flags);
    regs->ip = (unsigned long)&my_sys_read;
    reset_current_kprobe();
    return 1;
}
```

But when i try to import my module with `insmod` i got the following error : `Unknown symbol current_kprobe (err 0)`

If i don't call `reset_current_kprobe`, I got a exception in fault_handler with trap number 14 when i call the replaced function

I am using linux version 4.3.0-rc4 and I test it with qemu

Thank you !

Comment: `reset_current_kprobe` is static inline function, which implements via using `current_kprobe` variable. This variable is defined in `x86/kernel/kprobes/core.c` (with `DEFINE_PER_CPU`), but it is not exported for modules. BTW, it should be warning about this variable when you compile your module.

Comment: So if i can't use the reset_current_kprobe() function in modules, do you know how can i avoid the exeption (trap number 14) in fault_handler and properly alter execution path using kprobe ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: I am unsure whether `kprobe` can be applied for system calls, but you can replace `vfs_read` call instead. This function is called by `read` syscall implementation just after resolvind file descriptor. If you want to replace exactly system call, try to define replacement function with `SYSCALL_DEFINE3` macro. This way original function is defined.